# GAE Managed VM deploy gets stuck on Docker build

Tags: google-app-engine, google-container-registry, google-managed-vm

I'm trying to deply a custom app to a managed vm with:

`gcloud preview app deploy my_custom_app.yaml --version my_version --verbosity debug`

Every time I deploy, it makes it to this line, and then it stops, hangs for maybe 10 minutes, then exits with no error.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------ DOCKER BUILD OUTPUT -------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG: Looking for auth config
DEBUG: Sending auth config (u'https://bucket.gcr.io', u'https://appengine.gcr.io', u'https://eu.gcr.io', u'https://gcr.io', u'https://us.gcr.io', u'https://asia.gcr.io', u'https://b.gcr.io')
```

The deploy isn't finished. It created the VM, but inside the VM, `docker ps` is empty. So something is wrong with getting the docker image. I'm wondering if it could be an auth config issue...

Has anyone seen this? Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Sanity check is to restart dockerd, look at ports 8000 and 8080 and if there's any ports open, kill those processes. Probably won't resolve your issues but I have run into issues where gcloud opens ports and then fails to clean them up.

Comment: I've hit this same issue. Did anything fix it? I tried a few things, including finding the GCE instance that is building the docket managed vm. I `SSH`ed into it, and couldn't find anything unusual. I've opened this bug report for google, please let me know if you find a workaround: https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=456

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with the way we build and publish the docker image for you.  We've since updated the Cloud SDK to use a new service for building docker images.

Can you try running `gcloud components update`, and seeing if this is still an issue?

Comment: This seems to still behave the same way. Ideally it would be great to have some progress indication of the file upload. Its very hard to tell what is going on right now.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. When you see this message, it appears to be a hang, but under the hood, GAE is uploading files over the network (you can confirm this by checking your network connection), and if there are too many, it sometimes times out.

The reason it is taking so long is probably because you are uploading far more files than you intended. When you upload to managed VM, the `.gitignore` and the `skipfiles` within `app.yaml` are **not used** to determine which files to ignore. To fix this issue, you need to create a new file, called `.dockerignore` which lists which files should not be uploaded. Without this file, everything in your application directory will be uploaded, which can take a long time.

There is a lot of additional detail in the [bug report I submitted to Google developers](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=456).